# file_get_contents request with Authorization

Tags: php

I want send a get request with file_get_contents. This code returns `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.
How can I solve it?

```
<?php
define('API_KEY','eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...');

$data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'name' => 'test',
        'count' => '1000',
    )
);

$url = 'https://www.example.com/order';
$options = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'content' => $data,
    'header' =>
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
        "Authorization: Bearer ".API_KEY
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response1 = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
print_r($response1) ;
```

Also I tried this bottom code, but it returns the error again!

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/order?name=test&count=1000';
$options = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header' =>
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
        "Authorization: Bearer ".API_KEY
    )
);
```

Comment: Double-checking the URL is a good start - 404 not found

Comment: `\r\n` for the separation of multiple header lines is okay, but why a single `\n` after the last header?

Comment: The url is correct.

Comment: `'content' => $data` will cause this to be send as the request body, which for a GET request makes rather little sense. You should not specify `content`, and append the data as query string to the URL instead.

Comment: I tried to add the data parameters to the url (the second code I wrote) but again the same error occurred.

Comment: We can not possibly tell you why that happens, based on the info you have given us so far. We don’t know what API you are trying to communicate with there. Is there a specification of what exact request you are supposed to be sending here available anywhere?

Comment: yes, just needs change the name and count in orders. When I open this api link in my browser, it shows an error message (because the parameters are not set)
But now the problem is opening the link!